# Android app crashes on Java library pre-Lollipop

Tags: java, android, crash

I am building an Android app in Android Studio on a Mac running 10.10.5. The app works on current versions of Android, but on 4.2.2 (and I'm assuming anything pre-Lollipop), I get a java.lang.VerifyError on Constructor.newInstance. I'm guessing this is because Yosemite has Java 8, rather than Java 6 which is what Jelly Bean has. Am I wrong? If I am, then what is the issue, and if I'm not how can I install Java 6 in spite of Java 8 being there already?

The function is here:

```
public static <TAdapter extends Adapter<T, TDataViewHolder>, T, TDataViewHolder extends DataViewHolder> TAdapter newInstance(Context context, Class<TAdapter> adapterClazz, ListFragmentListener listFragmentListener, DataList<T> dataList, ImageHelperListener imageHelperListener, List<Object> params) {
    TAdapter result = null;

    Constructor<TAdapter> adapterConstructor = null;

    try {
        adapterConstructor = adapterClazz.getDeclaredConstructor(Context.class, ListFragmentListener.class, DataList.class, ImageHelperListener.class, List.class);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (adapterConstructor != null)
        if(dataList == null)
            dataList = new DataList<T>();
        try {
            result = adapterConstructor.newInstance(context, listFragmentListener, dataList, imageHelperListener, params);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InstantiationException | java.lang.InstantiationException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return result;
}

09-09 22:01:01.645    1837-1837/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.VerifyError: com/monscierge/monsciergesdk/adapters/Adapter
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
            at com.monscierge.monsciergesdk.helpers.GenericHelper.newInstance(GenericHelper.java:35)
            at com.monscierge.monsciergesdk.fragments.ListFragment.refreshListAdapter(ListFragment.java:258)
            at com.monscierge.monsciergesdk.fragments.PlaceListFragment.startGetData(PlaceListFragment.java:569)
            at com.monscierge.monsciergesdk.fragments.PlaceListFragment$2.onQueryTextSubmit(PlaceListFragment.java:60)
            at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.onSubmitQuery(SearchView.java:1151)
            at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.access$900(SearchView.java:104)
            at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$9.onEditorAction(SearchView.java:1129)
            at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:5328)
            at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:5218)
            at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.onKeyDown(AutoCompleteTextView.java:716)
            at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2609)
            at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:7205)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1359)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1920)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1395)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2370)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:49)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:258)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:49)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1847)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3701)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleImeFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3651)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2818)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You should able to compile against java 8 as its backward compatible. Can you post the code snippet

Comment: See my edit. As you can see, very abstract

Comment: Can you also post the stacktracke

Comment: Oh, and that Adapter class derives from ArrayAdapter. The crash happens before any of the constructors are hit.

Comment: Usually, `VerifyError` on a constructor means that a superclass or a field's class are not found.

Comment: So why would it not be able to find ArrayAdapter?

Answer (score 0):

Check your import code for ListFragment. Ensure that it's from the support library.

import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;

Also, all your fragment must import from and use the support libraries.

Comment: It is from the support library.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
try {
   result = adapterConstructor.newInstance(context, listFragmentListener, dataList, imageHelperListener, params);
} catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InstantiationException | java.lang.InstantiationException | InvocationTargetException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

On older versions multi-catch is not supported when you use reflection, so you need to modify the code in this way:

```
try {
   result = adapterConstructor.newInstance(context, listFragmentListener, dataList, imageHelperListener, params);
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```